# symfony 1.4 how to connect Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, symfony-1.4

In this project I must use symfony to connect to a Oracle database. But I don't how to do this.

Environment:

- LAMP,
- symfony 1.4,
- Oracle 10g

Oracle is installed in the server. First I need install the oracle client? Then how to configure symfony or PHP?

Comment: Did you perform few search on Google before posting this *non constructive* question?

Comment: Get PHP connecting to Oracle first. Then decide what ORM you're using - Doctrine or Propel. I got Propel 1.3 and Oracle working by debugging the connection system and determining the format of the DSN connection string.

Comment: (Voted to close, but if you can do some research as @j0k suggests, we'll gladly help you).

Answer (score 0):

The best way: Install the Zend Server/Community, because the server have the oci8 and pdo_oci extension compiled.

I recommend! ;)

Comment: yeah,i find the way to install and successfully,install OCI8 first.